# Sync Framework : How to check if a Row has been Synchronized with Miscrosoft Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Framework and Miscrosoft Azure in offline online mode, can i check if a specific row are synchronized just with the local database (means offline mode)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Fx doesnt mark rows if they've been synchronized or not. part of the logic to determine what to sync is to ask the destination about the last change they received.

easiest hack is to compare the timestamps on the tracking tables with a timestamp on the scope_info table